# Do+verb or just verb?

Tags: verbs, do-support, indian-english

I am from India. Here, we speak two sentences. Some say:

> They matter a lot.

Others say:

> They do matter a lot.

Which one is right and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are correct

> They matter a lot.
>   They do matter a lot.

"do" is an intensifier.